# Acceleration due to gravity in Ansys Fluent setup

Tags: ansys

For simulating a 2 dimensional problem in ANSYS Fluent, say if I have defined my geometry in an x-y plane. As per the problem statement the gravitational forces should act in the negative z direction. To achieve this which options should be set up in the setup part? In the taskbar of the user interface there's a define option which leads one to operating conditions, selecting one of which can add acceleration due to gravity values, however the z option is disabled. Please suggest an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Fluent can not simulate this case. you must specify a 3d problem. To reduce the computational cost, you can choose z-direction boundary conditions as periodic B.Cs.